# WordPress htaccess for every subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got this structure:

- public_html

  - site1.com
  - site2.com

After I redirect the URL site1.com to `/public_html/site1.com/index.php`
my URL is `site1.com/site1.com`. After I move to any other file, like contact.php
it goes to `site1.com/site1.com/contact.php`.

This is a WordPress site.
My SiteAdress URL is now `http://site1.com/site1.com`
WordPress URL is now `http://site1.com`

I need to get rid of this subfolder in the URL so it should look like:
site1.com/contact.php for example. I've tried many ways with .htacess but none worked properly.

Weird thing is that i can acess wp-login.php by just going to `site1.com/wp-login.php`, but when I try to access `site1.com/contact.php` it goes to index.php from my public_html/ directory.

I tried `RewriteRule ^site1.com/?(.*) /$1`
to get rid of this - this actually works well on htacess madewithlove
but it does not work on my website.

How should I accomplish that? Is that even possible?

By the way - should I use .htacess file in root directory or in site1.com/ directory?

Comment: Permalinks section from within WordPress admin panel should handle this part. Try removing your .htaccess, login to WordPress and hit update under PermaLinks section. Have you tried that?

Comment: Every permalink is like site1.com/site1.com/etc/
Is that okay?

Comment: That is very strange. What hosting are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure if thats the case, but it is home.pl.
Also I don't know if I've set up SiteAdress and WordPress URL properly.

Comment: I've tried that thing with permalinks and it crashed my site.
I've recorvered it by now but the problem still persists.

Comment: Check the RewriteBase is correct in htaccess